# Android Autofills For EditText is not Dark/Night Mode friendly

Tags: android, android-edittext, autofill

I have a email and password edit text. When Google Autofills popup, the text is not visible in dark mode/night mode. The rest of the app supports night mode with the help of themes.xml.

In the screen captures below, you can see that the text is not very visible in Night/Dark mode.

I have tried adding
`<item name="android:textColor">@color/my_color</item>` in the themes.xml for night and light modes but this doesn't do anything for me.

**Night Mode Autofill**

[image]

**Light Mode Autofill**

[image]

Comment: what about this tag   <item name="android:autofilledHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item>